# WWW::Mechanize::Firefox - remove welcome text

Tags: perl, firefox, browser-automation, www-mechanize, mozrepl

Whenever I start a [`WWW::Mechanize::Firefox`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize::Firefox) Perl script, the first thing that loads into the browser screen are the words "WWW::Mechanize::Firefox".

How do I disable this?

#### My Perl code

```
#!perl -w

use strict;

use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new( activate => 1 ); # bring the tab to the foreground

$mech->get('perlworkshop.de');

<>;
```

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: #!perl -w
    use strict;
    use WWW::Mechanize::Firefox;
    
    my $mech = WWW::Mechanize::Firefox->new(
        activate => 1, # bring the tab to the foreground
    );
    $mech->get('http://www.perlworkshop.de');
    
    <>;

Comment: @JeremyGwa: Please don't put code in comments: it is impossible to read. You should *edit* your question to give additional information.

Answer (score 1):

The banner is only displayed when `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` creates a new browser tab to work with, so the obvious way is to use an existing tab in the browser

If this isn't convenient then you must create a new `Firefox::Application` object, and use that to create a tab of your own without the banner

The problem is that `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` ordinarily passes its options to both of these steps, and writing the code manually breaks that connection. The best way is perhaps to subclass `WWW::Mechanize::Firefox` to provide a new constructor that behaves to your liking

May I ask why you want to do this? What is the nature of your application that you need to see specific results on the browser?